# How to convert 64 bit binary string to a double float in ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, binary, unpack

I am wondering how to convert a 64 bit binary string to a double float in ruby. The string that I have is as follows:

```
binaryString = "0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Using an online converter (http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html?) I know that the value should be 1.0. However, I'm attempting to use the ruby unpack to convert to double, and I'm not getting the correct result.

```
double_value = binaryString.unpack("G")
```

Gives me double_value = 1.3983819593719592e-76

I've tried other directives like "F" and "D", but none yield correct results.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Presumably `binaryString` is a string, so you need quotation marks on the right. (As written, `binaryString` is an integer whose digits are all zeros and ones, and whose two leading zeroes are of no significance) If it is meant to be a string, why not use it's integer value, `binaryString.to_i(2) # => 4607182418800017408`? You need to edit the question to correct or clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion. I added quotes to show that binaryString is, in fact, a string. I am not using the integer value because I know that binaryString correctly represents a double value of 1.0 per the online converter. I'm trying to get ruby to covert to the correct value. I want some way to have ruby yield 1.0 from the binaryString given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unpack` expects binary data, so you have to `pack` your bit string first using `B`:

```
b = '0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

[b].pack('B*').unpack1('G')
#=> 1.0
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for your help!